# leaflet popups, setting an on close event

Tags: javascript, popup, leaflet

I'm aware you can set an "on popup close" event on the `map` object in leaflet, is there any way to set that on a per-popup basis?

If I have a layer taken from an event like so...

```
var layer = event.layer;

var bound = layer.bindPopup(
  "blah",
  {closeButton: false, closeOnClick: false}
);

var popUp = bound.openPopup();
```

I would like to conditionally set an on-close event for this popup based on a condition. The issue I am facing is that when they draw a shape, I open a popup to allow them to name it. However, if they click on the shape while this popUp is open, it runs the "click" event which opens ANOTHER popup to edit it. I'd like to avoid this and make it so that if they close the first popup without setting a name, it removes the shape entirely.

Comment: I was just searching the syntax for {closeButton: false}, thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no an onClose, but there is an onRemove. This is fired when you close the popup:

`marker.getPopup().on('remove', function() {
    //Your code here
});`

Answer (score 0):

```
// layer on click event
    layer.on("click", function (e) {
      // get the mouse coordinates
      coordsMap = e.latlng;

      // define the content popup
      let content = "Text Popup or Content";

      // create and display popup on map
      let popup = L.popup()
        .setLatLng(coordsMap)
        .setContent(content)
        .openOn(map);

      // close event popup
      popup.on("remove", function () {
        alert("popup remove");
        //other instructions
      });
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).